# "Save as" on clientside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, activex

Is there any way to set some headers, like `content-disposition` : `attachment; filename=somefile.xml` and make a postback on the client side to make a save-as button of a file? The file is generated using active-x.

Or is there any other way to choose the location for the file?

I'm currently saving the generated xml files next to my html file, but I would like some browse similar functionality. As long as I get the path as a string, I can fix the rest myself.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean you’d like the user to be forced to “download” the file, rather than merely view it in their browser?

Comment: @ThomasEdwards It will never be viewed in the browser. I just want the user to speficy the path of where they want the xml file to be generated.

Comment: Do you mean locally on the server, or on their local drive?

Comment: This is because of many good security reasons, not possible! The destination where downloads are stored have to be setted up by the user in the browser. No way to manipulate it!

Comment: @Armin Not entirely true; I used document.location.href and stored files next to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With html5 file's API, you can actually create a blob on the runtime and download it on the client side. But since you talking ActiveX, you're probably using IE and this example won't work. You can try it in Chrome or Firefox.

http://jsfiddle.net/francisfortier/eq8CC/

Comment: Thanks , but this needs to work down to ie7. However, ill accept this, since its the most correct answer